# Aligning of the node content and prevent linebreaks

Tags: genealogytree

I've got two questions:

At first I encountered some difficulty aligning the text inside the nodes. My aim is to get the name aligned to the center and the rest of the content aligned to the left. Since it is not possible to inset this into the name field of the database, this has to be done in the processor I guess.

Secondly I noticed that linebreaks are made in the node content if the space isn't enough (of course). Since in my opinion it looks ugly if the date spans over two lines, I'd like to prevent the processor (at least I guess it is the processor) from inserting linebreaks at this particular place.
[image: Here is an image of how the Date spans over two lines]

I use

```
\genealogytree[
        template=signpost,
        database content interpreter,
        database format=full,
        list separators hang,
        edges=rounded]{ input{file} }
```

to make the Tree.

I hope someone of you knows how to do this, I already searched on the Internet and tried to get a glimpse on the code of the database processor, but I didn't found the right place to look.

Edit: As requested, in addition, a minimal working code:

```
\documentclass{standalone} %or standalone
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\gtrset{info separators={\par}{. }{}{}} %no period after comment



\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        %templates: signpost, database traditional
        \genealogytree[
                template=signpost,
                database content interpreter,
                database format=full,
                list separators hang,
                edges=rounded]{

                sandclock{
                        child{
                                g[female]{
                                        female,
                                        name = {name \surn{name}},
                                        birth- = {1997-09-20},
                                }
                        }
                        child{
                                g[male]{
                                        male,
                                        name = {name \surn{name}},
                                        birth- = {2001-05-23},
                                }
                        }
                }
                }
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Could you expand you code snippet to a [minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that)? It should start with a `\documentclass`, end with a `\end{document}` and contain only what is necessary for the problem.

Comment: Added a minimum working example

Comment: Second question: use \mbox{no line break}.

Comment: Hm, ok yes setting the date in a mbox would prevent it, but I don't find where to set it that the date is placed inside a mbox (and yes I'm pretty new to (la)tex and am not that experienced)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use the signpost template it will be left-aligned. To then handle the name in a special way one way is to misuse the parameter which is actually meant for setting a special font for the name.

I set bigger boxes in the example so the difference between alignments is clearer.

```
\documentclass{standalone} %or standalone
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}

\gtrset{info separators={\par}{. }{}{}} %no period after comment

\gtrset{name font=\hfil}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % templates: signpost, database traditional
  \genealogytree[
  %% template=signpost,
  node size=5cm,
  database content interpreter,
  database format=full,
  list separators hang,
  edges=rounded]{
    sandclock{
      child{
        g[female]{
          female,
          name = {name \surn{name}},
          birth- = {1997-09-20},
        }
      }
      child{
        g[male]{
          male,
          name = {name \surn{name}},
          birth- = {2001-05-23},
        }
      }
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As for question #2 I'm not sure what you want to happen instead in the example you gave.

[image]

Comment: Yes question #2 refers that the result should look like yours (I gues you removed the signpost template) so that the word "september" is not split into two lines instead I want the box to become more wide so that the word fits into it. (Recently I experienced that if tex isn't able to split the word (since it is a familyname in my case) and it doesn't fit into the box under some circumstances the box doesn't become more wide instead the last characters of the word are cut off)

Comment: And I don't know how you managed to compile your code but if I try to run it I get this error: `! Infinite glue shrinkage found in a paragraph. \gtrlistseparator ->\par \hangindent =\tcbfitdim \hangafter =1\def \gtrlists... l.33 } ? ! Infinite glue shrinkage found in a paragraph. \gtrlistseparator ->\par \hangindent =\tcbfitdim \hangafter =1\def \gtrlists... l.33 } ?` Don't you get this error too?

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `\hfil` and not `\hss`. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: Ok, this works now, thanks.

Did you understand my second question now?